# "Edit document in Word" with Chrome now produces an error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, chrome

I'm a user of SharePoint, not an admininistrator/installer. I couldn't retrieve the SharePoint version that my company uses.

Since the latest version of Chrome (version 46.0.2490.86 m, released on November 10), I can't use the functionality "edit document in Word" anymore. It used to work in previous versions. This functionality also works properly now with Firefox (latest version) and Internet Explorer (latest version).

Instead, when I click "edit document in Word", I keep getting an error saying:

> The document could not be opened for editing. A Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application could not be found to edit the document.

This issue is reproduced on every installation of Chrome in my team. Chrome unfortunately updates systematically so we can't know for sure which previous version we had.

My questions are:

- Is this a Chrome- or SharePoint-specific issue?
- If it is a Chrome issue, is it linked to my installation of Chrome or to the version of Chrome in general?
- If it is my installation, what should I do to have it fixed?

Versions:

- MS Word : Edition 2010 pro ; 14.0.7153.5000 (32-bit)
- Chrome: 46.0.2490.86 m (32-bit)

Comment: Looks Microsoft office issue to me.

Comment: @BhaskarDhone Possible, but I have my doubts since, as I mentioned, it's working fine in both Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Do you happen to know if your Chrome browser had not been updated for some time? Also, when you click a document does it open in Word or does Chrome just download a copy?

Comment: Can you please also share your microsoft office version . Also is it 32 bit or 64 bit.  and Same details for chrome.

Comment: @Submits I don't know if Chrome hadn't been updated in a while (yet I think Chrome is always up to date). I only know everyone has the same version now. When I click a document, it downloads a PDF version of it; when I use the document's dropdown menu and select "edit in Word", it should open directly as it did previously and does in FF & IE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just under a year ago Google removed the NPAPI plugin from its Chrome browser. Since this change one is no longer able to do a number of things with the Chrome browser in SharePoint.

It could be that your Chrome had not been updated for some time and the recent update has taken your browser to a version that has the NPAPI plugin removed.

Up until recently there was a workaround available, but since September this year even that has been phased out.

Microsoft were supposed to address this issue with updates to SharePoint, but it seems these have not been rolled out as of yet.

More details [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_integration__sharepoint/archive/2015/04/24/unable-to-open-sharepoint-documents-in-rich-client-from-chrome.aspx).

Comment: I've checked several consequences mentioned in your link. They all apply. so I guess the removal of NPAPI is the issue.

Comment: Yes and no guarantees it'll work any time soon. Another possible workaround is to use the IETab Chrome extension. Seems to work for others, but I haven't personally tried it.

Answer (score 0):

The most powerful way to use Sharepoint from Chrome is to do it with the Chrome IE Tab extension.  Add Auto URLs to configure the extension so all of the Sharepoint URLs are opened by IE Tab, then you will be able to directly edit your Office documents.